# "Serial downvote" no meu utilizador

Tags: suporte, voto-contra, serial-voting

Na última hora recebi [36 votos a negativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/223/zuul?tab=reputation):

- 10 votos há 42 minutos;

  [image: Captura de Tela]
- 2 votos há 32 minutos:

  [image: Captura de Tela]
- 7 votos há 28 minutos:

  [image: Captura de Tela]
- 10 votos há 27 minutos:

  [image: Captura de Tela]
- 7 votos há 26 minutos:

  [image: Captura de Tela]

## Pergunta

Isto é um caso de votos em série por um/vários utilizadores ou efectivamente são votos fidedignos de utilizadores a manifestarem a sua discordância com os conteúdos/perguntas?

Comment: Tem toda a cara de serial downvote. Se for mesmo, o sistema vai reverter.

Comment: @Zuul Você tentou recentemente ajudar algum usuário novo?

Comment: Isso tem cara de um mesmo usuário com duas contas.

Comment: @utluiz Sorry, estava AFK. O meu dia é ajudar ajudar ajudar :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Essa tua edição na pergunta... ainda não consegui ter tempo para ir ler sobre esse assunto! :)

Comment: Hoje foi meu dia, espero que reverta.

Comment: @bigown A mim reverteu +/- 24h depois (penso que o tratamento destes casos ocorreu uma vez por dia)

Comment: É sempre na madrugada. O bom é que esses serial killers são burros :)

Comment: @bigown É preciso algum trabalho para "enganar" o sistema de forma a não existir reversão... mas mesmo passando por cima da "primeira linha de defesa", uma bandeira ao homem do diamante e temos a "segunda linha de devesa" em ação :) _(**ps** estive a ver e é mesmo serial no teu caso também, amanhã já deve estar resolvido)_

Comment: Acabei de tomar uma série dessas, provavelmente em retaliação a algum voto de fechar post. Sinalizei ao amg diamante não pela rep, mas pra cortar as asas da criança.